# Does -static-libstdc++ GCC flag affect the generation of a static library (*.a) on Linux

Tags: c++, gcc, static

The question comes from the following scenario:

There is a static c++ library **A** and an executable **B**, which links to **A**. I want **B** to be independent of c++ runtime.

I know that with MSVC, if **A** is compiled with `/MD` flag, then B will definitely depends on msvc*.dll.

But I am confused about whether `-static-libstdc++` plays the same role for GCC on linux.

My question is with GCC on linux, do I need to use `-static-libstdc++` when I COMPILE **A**, or it is just an linker flag and does not affect **A** at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try it and find out.  Just generate your library both ways and compare the file sizes and perhaps the symbol lists using `nm` and/or `objdump`.

Comment: Also try `ldd` on the library to see if it has any dynamic dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is yes (but have not tried it).

The reason is that code accesses symbols in dynamic libraries differently from static symbols (symbols in the executable). This is library A in your case.

For static symbols, these are resolved to memory addresses when the executable is linked. In fact, the names of the symbols do not have to be saved in the executable at all (this is called a "stripped" executable).

For symbols in dynamic libraries, the names of symbols do have to appear, and they are accessed by code in the executable to load the symbol (maybe using functions like `dlopen` and `dlsym`.)